# tuple in redis / python: can store, not retrieve

Tags: python, redis

So, I've got redis working with python -- exciting!

I need to store a tuple and retrieve it / parse it later.  Construct below isn't working, I think because the returned tuple is quoted -- there is a quote on either end of it.

It seems to me that the quotes indicate that it isn't actually a tuple, but rather a string.

So does anyone know how to get redis to actually return a working tuple?  Thanks!

```
>>> tup1 = ('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.32093240923490, 25.239502352390)
>>> r.lpush('9999', tup1)
1L
>>> r.lpop('9999')
"('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.3209324092349, 25.23950235239)"
>>> v = r.lpop('9999')
>>> test=v[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already `popped` and element from `v` and the element you are trying to retrieve no longer exists.

Try this:

```
>>> tup1 = ('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.32093240923490, 25.239502352390)
>>> r.lpush('9999', tup1)
>>> v = r.lpop('9999')
>>> test = eval(v)[0]
```

Since the return type is a string, you need `eval` to evaluate the type

Comment: Doh but... didn't work.  Yes, that was idiotic of me to pop the stack and then look for a value.  Sigh.....   However, test comes back as ( --> takes the double quote, then open parens, closes out with a single quote = open parens.  v[1] is a single quote, v[2] = 2    Not good.

Comment: Karthikr nailed it.  After my v line, add this (or his version):
z = eval(v)
print z[0] ----> '2011-04-05'  
etc.

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to get the tuple back as such, I recommend using 'pickle'.

```
>>> tup1 = ('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.32093240923490, 25.239502352390)
>>> import pickle
>>> r.lpush('9999', pickle.dumps(tup1))
1L
>>> v = pickle.loads(r.lpop('9999'))
>>> v
('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.3209324092349, 25.23950235239)
>>> type(v)
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with karthikr's solution, but `literal_eval` from the standard lib is usually recommended as the safe alternative, as `eval` can execute arbitrary code if you give it funny input

```
>>> tup1 = "print('Dont use eval! ' * 2)"
>>> r.lpush('9999', tup1)
>>> v = r.lpop('9999')
>>> test = eval(v)
Dont use eval! Dont use eval!
```

`literal_eval` will create your tuple (or list or dict), but won't run functions.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> tup1 = ('2011-04-05', 25.2390232323, 0.32093240923490, 25.239502352390)
>>> tup2 = "print('Dont use eval! ' * 2)"
>>> r.lpush('9999', tup2, tup1)
>>> v1 = r.lpop('9999')
>>> print(literal_eval(v1) == tup1)
True

>>> literal_eval(r.lpop('9999'))  # ==> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```